# Get records that match all corresponding records on conditional join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a business problem that I formulated to the following example for easier communication. 
Say I have three tables `Employee`, `Project`, `EmpWorkProj`. `EmpWorkProj` is used to link employees and the projects they worked on (or link table between `Employee` and `Project`). This is an example of the table data:
Table: `Employee`

```
EmployeeID  EmpName
1           Alex
2           Pete
3           Mike
```

Table: `Project`

```
ProjectID   ProjectCity
11          NY
22          LA
33          NY
44          LA
```

Table: `EmpWorkProj`

```
EmployeeID  ProjectID
1            11
1            33
1            22
2            11
3            33
3            44
```

What I want to return is the employee who works on all projects with city `'NY'`. In this example I want to return `Alex` because he is the only employee who worked on project id `11` and `33`. 
I would really appreciate a solution that uses standard sql (can't deploy recursive CTEs, dynamic sql or cursors). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this using `group by` and `having`.  For each employee, count the number of projects they are in with NY as the city.  Then, in the `having` clause, see if that is all the projects:

```
select ewp.employeeid
from EmpWorkProj ewp join
     Project p
     on ewp.projectid = p.projectid
where p.projectcity = 'NY'
group by ewp.employeeid
having count(*) = (select count(*) from project where projectcity = 'NY')
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. This returned the right results but the query took 5 minutes to execute on actual tables. I am trying to solve it using set operators. Do you think would it be possible to find a solution without groupings?. Thanks

Comment: @Ala . . . Unless you have a lot of data (millions of rows), then I would expect the query to be pretty fast -- on a properly built database.  Do you have indexes on all the appropriate columns?

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. I actually have millions of rows. My original problem is not about the tables that I mentioned. But I figured out an answer without using Group by. I posted it but selected your answer as the answer because it helped me figure out that other answer.

Comment: Your answer is quite clever and I'm glad it works for you.  I upvoted it.

Answer (score 3):

This also works:

```
declare @e table(EmployeeID int,  EmpName varchar(10))
declare @p table(ProjectID int,  ProjectCity varchar(10))
declare @ep table(EmployeeID int,  ProjectID int)

insert into @e values
(1 ,          'Alex'),
(2 ,          'Pete'),
(3 ,          'Mike')

insert into @p values
(11,          'NY'),
(22,          'LA'),
(33,          'NY'),
(44,          'LA')

insert into @ep values
(1,            11),
(1,            33),
(1,            22),
(2,            11),
(3,            33),
(3,            44)

;with cte as(select ProjectID from @p where ProjectCity = 'NY')
select ep.EmployeeID
from @ep ep
outer apply(select * from cte  except select ProjectID from @ep e where e.EmployeeID = ep.EmployeeID) o
group by ep.EmployeeID
having MAX(o.ProjectID) is null
```

Answer (score 2):

So the solution I was looking for is this, Thanks to Giorgi and Gordon to help me see it

```
SELECT E.EmpName
FROM Employees e 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ProjectID 
                  FROM dbo.Project p
                  WHERE p.ProjectCity='NY'
                  EXCEPT 
                  SELECT ProjectID
                  FROM dbo.EmpWorkProj ep
                  WHERE ep.EmployeeID= e.EmployeeID);
```

Answer (score -1):

> `SELECT e.EmpName 
>   FROM Employee e, EmpWorkProj ewp,Project p
>   WHERE ewp.ProjectID=p.ProjectID and p.ProjectCity='NY' and ewp.EmployeeID=e.EmployeeID;`

Comment: Whats wrong with this?? Atleast have the courtesy to reply!

Comment: You should write generic queries and not select directly something to adjust result to output. Consider this: you have table with rows(2, 3, 4) and you want a sum. You should write something like `SELECT SUM(Column) From Table` rather than `SELECT 9 AS RESULT`

Comment: You mean something like this?